# How do vertical saws avoid cutting their support

Tags: panel-saw

I'm wondering how this is possible. Vertical panel saws don't cut into the support beams the stock is resting on while being cut.

Making horizontal cuts I have seen that the support rails are moved out of the way, but how does that work when sawing vertically? Are there some predefined positions? I don't think so as I have seen one in action and it seemed to be free to cut anywhere.

Can anyone working with such a saw explain how this is possible?

Comment: It really looks like there are some predefined positions where the cut can be made as visible [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXWJytO5bh4&feature=youtu.be&t=1m32s)

Comment: Some vertical saws don't have a problem with potentially sawing into the supports as it is the workpiece that moves and the saw blade remains stationary. If the saw blade is free to move back and forth then obviously there must be a slot of some kind for it to travel in.

Comment: In the video that @Zveratko linked to, you'll see that for vertical cuts the saw moves and the workpiece is stationery, and for horizontal cuts the saw is stationery and the workpiece moves.  That's what I've seen when I've watched the saws being used.  Presumably there's a predefined position for vertical cuts.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like the saw blade actually does cut into (not through) the horizontal backing strips.  The red strips are extruded plastic which are probably replaced from time to time.

[At this location](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXWJytO5bh4&feature=youtu.be&t=1m32s) in the referenced video a slit can be seen in the horizontal backing strip.  It appears that the vertical panel saw that is depicted in the film is fairly new and the camera work is such that existing cuts are not readily visible.

Comment: But imagine such a heavy duty saw making hundreds of cuts each day. They will be forced to replace the rails quite often. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFkL7QkOBRY&feature=youtu.be&t=1m6s) it is clearly visible he is locking in some position and also you can see only couple of railing cuts through the video I suspect at the exact locking positions.

Comment: Good point, but in practice a shop would specify to keep the saw in a stationary horizontal location and set the stops as is seen in the second video that you referenced.  Change the saw position only when necessary.  In the second video you can see more locations where cuts have been made previously.  I am certain that a trained operator can move the saw to the location of a previous cut, then set the stops.  When there gets to be too many cuts, change the backup strips and hire a new operator.